# Why does passing the plot type ('scatter', 'bar', etc.) as string variable does not work? (using <Plot ... /> from react-plotly.js)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, plotly

I am using TypeScript, React and Plotly in my project and would like to know if it is possible to pass the plot type specification using a variable. Something like this (which is not a working code example and only used to indicate what I mean)

```js
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

var plotType: string = 'bar';

return (
    <Plot
        data={[{
            x: [1,2,3,4],
            y: [1,2,3,4],
            type: 'bar'        // this works
            type: plotType     // this doesn't
        }]}

    />
);
```

It's not really an issue since I go about the whole 'data' thing using a state property, but I still don't get why it works with the literal string but not with a variable.

The error is something like 'string' cannot be assigned since '"bar"|"scatter"|"line" ...' is expected.

For a working example I can only refer to the [react-plotly](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js) github repos, where one can use the given quickstart example and try to substitute the string in `type: 'scatter'` with a variable.

PS.: I am quiet new to TS or JS in general so I might be using wrong/misleading terms unknowningly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isnt entirely evident in their docs but, this is actually a TS feature that the plotly devs are using.

I can say

```
type MyType = string;
```

then if I say

```
const myVar = '123';
```

TS will be perfectly happy. On the other hand, I could restrict other devs on what actual values they assign to MyType like

```
type MyType = 'bar' | 'pie' | 'scatter';
```

which is exactly what plotly has done. and then if a dev says

```
<Plot type={'123'} />
```

TS will throw an error because '123' isnt one of the options.

Now, you say, but my plotType variable IS one of those options. While thats true, you typed it as :string. So, when TS type checks is compares the PlotType type inside Plotly which is a limited set of strings to the string type. Thus, you have a mismatched type. In your case you could have said

```
var plotType: Plotly.PlotType = 'bar';
```

since the types now match, this would be acceptable. In fact, in this case you wouldnt even be able to accidently change the value of plotType to something not a part of Plotly.PlotType because TS would complain now.